# hadoop classCastException

Tags: hadoop, classcastexception

I encounter the following error using hadoop 0.18.3

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable

I defined my mapper as:

```
public class HadoopMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<Text,DoubleWritable,Text,DoubleWritable> {
// The Karmasphere Studio Workflow Log displays logging from Apache Commons Logging, for example:
// private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog("HadoopMapper");

@Override
public void map(Text key, DoubleWritable value, OutputCollector<Text, DoubleWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
        throws IOException {
//        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    Random generator = new Random();
     int i;

     final int iter = 100000;

     for (i =0; i < iter; i++)
     {
     double x = generator.nextDouble();
     double y = generator.nextDouble();

     double z;

     z = x*x + y*y;

     if (z <= 1){
         output.collect(new Text("VALUE"), new DoubleWritable(1));
     }else{
         output.collect(new Text ("VALUE"), new DoubleWritable(0));
     }
     }


  }
}
```

and reducer class as

```
public class HadoopReducer extends MapReduceBase implements    Reducer<Text,DoubleWritable,Text,DoubleWritable> {
// The Karmasphere Studio Workflow Log displays logging from Apache Commons Logging, for example:
// private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog("HadoopReducer");

@Override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<DoubleWritable> value, OutputCollector<Text, DoubleWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
        throws IOException {
    // TODO code reducer logic here
//        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");

    double pi = 0;
     double inside = 0;
     double outside = 0;

     while (value.hasNext())
     {
     if (value.next().get() == (long)1)
     inside++;
     else
     outside++; 
     }

     pi = (4*inside)/(inside + outside);

     output.collect(new Text ("pi"), new DoubleWritable(pi));
    }
}
```

I set the jobconf as:

```
    public static void initJobConf(JobConf conf) {
// Generating code using Karmasphere Protocol for Hadoop 0.18
// CG_GLOBAL

// CG_INPUT_HIDDEN
    conf.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
// CG_MAPPER_HIDDEN
conf.setMapperClass(HadoopMapper.class);

// CG_MAPPER

// CG_PARTITIONER_HIDDEN
conf.setPartitionerClass(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.HashPartitioner.class);

// CG_PARTITIONER

 // CG_COMPARATOR_HIDDEN
conf.setOutputKeyComparatorClass(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.Comparator.class);

// CG_COMPARATOR

// CG_COMBINER_HIDDEN

// CG_REDUCER_HIDDEN
conf.setReducerClass(HadoopReducer.class);

// CG_REDUCER
   conf.setNumReduceTasks(1);

   // CG_OUTPUT_HIDDEN
    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     conf.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);
    // CG_OUTPUT

     // Others
    }
```

I can not find a Inputformat that matches  and KeyValueTextInputFormat.class in conf.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class) is , so how to deal with it? Can I subclass and Can you help me with an example?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

KeyValueTextInputFormat expects as input a text key and a text value separated by a SEPARATOR_CHARACTER (by default tab). You're trying to transform it into a DoubleWritable which by default is not possbile.

So, modify your mapper to :
    Mapper< Text,Text,Text,DoubleWritable >

and the map method accordingly and then transform the text to double by yourself.